# Open URL in a new window not working in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I am trying to open a URL in a new window **(not in new tab)**.

I wrote the following code, but it would not open the URL in a new window; instead, it would open the URL in a new tab.

I have tried it in both Firefox and Chrome, but it has the same behavior in both browsers.

**My Flex code is:**

```
var path:String = "http://stackoverflow.com";
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(path);
navigateToURL(urlRequest,"_blank");
```

Comment: That's not a bug, but a browser feature - to protect from sites opening numerous new windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you testing on local environment or server?

If this is not the case, there also a similar question with accepted answer. [Need help AS3 navigateToURL opening new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731223/need-help-as3-navigatetourl-opening-new-window)

Also the browser's settings should determine if that's actually a new window or a new tab. The user's preferences will determine the result

Hope will be possible to help, somehow. Good luck!

- **window:String** (default = *null*) — The browser window or HTML frame in which to display the document indicated by the *request* parameter. You can enter the name of a specific window or use one of the following values:
- "*_self*" specifies the current frame in the current window.
- "*_blank*" specifies a new window.
- "*_parent*" specifies the parent of the current frame.
- "*_top*" specifies the top-level frame in the current window.

If you do not specify a value for this parameter, a new empty window is created. In the stand-alone player, you can either specify a new ("*_blank*") window or a named window. The other values don't apply.

---

**Note:** When code in a SWF file that is running in the local-with-filesystem sandbox calls the *navigateToURL()* function and specifies a custom *window* name for the window parameter, the window name is transfered into a random name. The name is in the form "*_flashXXXXXXXX*", where each X represents a random hexadecimal digit. Within the same session (until you close the containing browser window), if you call the function again and specify the same name for the *window* parameter, the same random string is used.**

Comment: I am testing on local environment.

Comment: As you suggested link in that link they suggest to use URLLoader to call php page and pass parameter. But my issue is diffrent i want to open new window with specified link.

Comment: I got your point now. I have tested and it's always opening a new window. Maybe the browser's settings should determine if that's actually a new window or a new tab. The user's preferences will determine the result.

Comment: Ohh yes you right. I change browser settings and now it opens in new window. Thanks for help.